# Problem uploading apk to google play console (android:exported)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I recently updated the targetSDK to version 31, after that, I started receiving the following error when uploading the apk to the google play console.

I have already made the necessary corrections reported at: [developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported), however, I continue to receive the error.

In the file below I have set android:exported="true" at all times. However, I previously followed the recommendation:

> If the app component includes the LAUNCHER category, set
> android:exported to true. In most other cases, set android:exported to
> false.

It still didn't work.

BuildScript:

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
```

See my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="farmacia.digital.com"
>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
      android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL"
      android:value="https://exp.host/@datalytics/farmacia-digital"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION"
      android:value="40.0.0"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL"
      android:value="default"
    />

    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
      android:exported="true"
    >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="farmaciadigital" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"
      android:exported="false"
    />

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
      android:value="true"
    />
    <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/blue"
    />

    <receiver
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions"
    />
    <receiver
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher"
    />
    <receiver
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver"
      android:exported="false"
    >
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
      android:exported="false"
    >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, did you try this <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"
      android:exported="true"
    />

Comment: Is it necessary? In the documentation it states that only those who have IntentFilter need this information.

Comment: you need to set the exported attribute on any  activities, services, or (broadcast receivers that use intent filters). Your activity `DevSettingsActivity` does not have this attribute set. The part of the manual that says "that use intent filters" only refers to broadcast receivers.

Comment: From what I understand, adds android:exported only if there are intent filters, see: If your app targets Android 12 or higher and contains activities, services, or broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must explicitly declare the android:exported attribute for these app components.

Comment: anyway, even putting android:exported in the suggested place, I get the same error message.

Comment: You can try checking the merged manifest. Maybe there are some dependencies that that declare components (activities etc) the old way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Activities, services and applications inside of Android Manifest should have the `exported` tag.

I can see that you have missed that inside of the `Application` tag.

Also I advise you to use an emulator or device which has an API level above 31 (android 12 and above) to run the application in debug mode instead of creating a release build and uploading to the PlayStore every time.

After doing that, if you realize that all tags have the `exported` tag set, this means that you might have some libraries that may not have this set.

So as a solution you'd need to manually resolve this inside of `node_modules` or, the more reasonable and logical approach, which is upgrading the dependencies.

If the library is no longer maintained, you'd have to go with the 1st approach, or find a replacement.

**For Finding the libraries:**

[image]

Open Android Studio, and open Android Manifest and press on Merged Manifest at the bottom, this will show you the list of manifests inside of the 3rd party packages that are added to your project as shown in the image above.

The ones that do not have `exported` set will show in red at the right hand side of the screen.

Just go over them one by one and try to upgrade them and that should fix your issue. If not, add the `exported` tag manually to the problematic libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Check the merged manifest file. The final manifest of an Android project is the result of merging together the relevant parts of all the manifset from every library/module in the project. If you corrected your entire manifest file, then the warning comes from a dependency's manifest. Since you are using react-native, is very likely some RN libraries (which are pasted into your project as modules) are outdated and aren't updated to handle SDK 31.

The merged manifest should be in `<project>/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests directory`
Otherwise, use the search function over the entire project directory and check all the manifest.xml files.

Answer (score 2):

You could see that `<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />` doesn't have the exported tag. Adding `android:exported='false'` should be enough.

Regards.

Comment: I tried to export by adding the tag you suggested, even so, it still doesn't accept it in the google play console, same error message.

Comment: And if you put the same in the rest of receivers?

Comment: One of the attempts was putting it on all receivers too, unfortunately same error. I'll check the merged manifest as suggested in the question comment.